# react-dom error when going back after updating the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm stumbling across a strange error in my react project. Everything works fine if I go from the home page to the next page. The next page hits an API and updates the Redux store. Now, if I hit the back button or try to go back through the react-router-dom(`history.go(-1)`), my page throws this error:

[image]

Here is a [working CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-j5ioj?file=/app/index.jsx:0-26) to the app. Here is how to reproduce the error:

- Enter some text in the input box.
- Then hit the search button.
- Click on browser's button or click on the back button on the page.
- Observe that the home page is blank. And it shows the above error.

Note that if I don't update the store and then go back to previous page, then everything works fine.

Comment: why is `routes` lowercased and called like a function and not a component? I think that might be your problem. Should be `Routes` and `<Routes />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file [`app/screens/EmployeeDetails/employeeDetails.jsx`](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-night-j5ioj?file=/app/screens/EmployeeDetails/employeeDetails.jsx) you have:

```js
useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchEmployee(name)), [])
```

The implicit return here attempts to use the result of the dispatch as the [`cleanup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) for the `useEffect`. Your error occurs because it tries to call the cleanup function since you didn't return `undefined`, but you returned a `Promise` instead of a `function` which the `useEffect` expected for it's cleanup (hence the error: 'is not a function').

You should add curly brackets to avoid the implicit return:

```js
useEffect(() => { dispatch(fetchEmployee(name)) }, [])
```